# Problems using Zend Tools on Server environment: Missing Profile, Wrong default Paths

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-tool

I have a complex error that may or may not be connected to the Zend installation provided by 1und1 Webhosting which I am using.

Here are some of the Symptoms first:

Creating a project using:

```
"~/myzenddir> zf create project myzend"
```

causes

```
  <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  mkdir() 
    [<a href='function.mkdir'>function.mkdir</a>]: 
    Permission denied in <b>
    /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Tool/Project ...
    ...  /Provider/Project.php</b>        
    on line <b>55</b><br />
```

Using instead:

```
"~/myzenddir> zf create project 
      ~/myzenddir/myzend 
      myzend 
      ~/myzenddir/myzend.profile"
```

creates the Project structure. 
In this case however the profile - file is missing.

This causes "A project profile was not found." when enabling layouts:

```
"~/myzenddir> zf enable layout"
```

So the Problem - brought to a point - is:

- My Zend installation is generating content in its library location instead of the current directory.
- Create project doesn't create the profile file as documented.

I have provided the following configurations initially to use zend with my hosting provider "1&1":

.htaccess:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
Options -MultiViews
```

php.ini:

```
include_path = .:/usr/lib/php5:/usr/share/php/ ...
... libzend-framework-php:/usr/share/zend-framework
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path to your public directory when calling zf (should be something like "/kunden/homepages/path_to_your_public_folder/htdocs/myzend"). This should work, the other way it uses the path to the library and that's protected in 1and1 hostings.